# onClick php PHP Function then redirect

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a page full of links that go to pdf's I want to track which links are being clicked. I thought I could do something like follows but am having issues:

```
<?
    function track($link)
    {
    $sql = "UPDATE database WHERE something = 'something';
    $db = new connection();
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    if($result){                 
                  header( 'Location: http://mywebsite/docs/. $link .' ) ;
                }
    }
?>
```

and my HTML would look like:

```
<a onClick="track(my_file_.pdf")">File Name</a>
```

Ok it looks like I am just going to use the link to pass the file name to a php script and once that is done I will redirect the user to the pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by others you are mixing client side code (the browser code) with the server side code (php). You need to change the html to be

```
<a href="redirector.php?file=my_file_.pdf">File Name</a>
```

You then need to create a php script to handle the request. For example redirector.php could look like this:

```
<?php
function track($link) {
    $sql = "UPDATE database WHERE something = 'something'";
    $db = new connection();
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    if ($result) {
        header('Location: http://mywebsite/docs/' . $link);
        exit;
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
     track($_GET['file']);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you are mixing JavaScript (client-site) with PHP (server-site) - will not work

It look like you want to count how many time pdfs are clicked (delivered) - consider other ways:

- check access log and count
- if your PDF is created by script - make update before created
- execute AJAX request onclick which will update your database

Answer (score 2):

Try using the href attribute instead of onClick() which is for javascript

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a double quote after 'something' you can't call php function like that after the page is rendered. Go with ajax or a GET/POST to your php script

Answer (score 1):

you should try with jquery ajax

```
<a onClick="track('my_file_.pdf')">File Name</a>


<script>
function track(link)
{
$.ajax({
  url: "update.php?link="+link,
  success: function(data){
    if(data=="DONE")
    {
        window.location="http://mywebsite/docs/"+link;
    }

  }
});
}
</script>
```

in update.php

```
<?php

$link=$_GET['link'];
 $sql = "UPDATE database WHERE something = 'something'";
    $db = new connection();
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    if($result){ 
        echo "DONE";
    }

?>
```